# Show that Cl$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{105})) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Show that Cl$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{105}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{105})$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{105}}{2}]$, disc $K=105$ and sign $K=(2,0)$.

I find elements of norm $-6$ i.e. $\frac{1+\sqrt{105}}{2}+4$ and norm $-5$ i.e. $10+\sqrt{105}$.

I calculated $M_K=\sqrt{105}/2<6$.

$2\mathbb{Z}_K=p_2p_2'$ where $p_2=(2,\alpha+1), p_2'=(2,\alpha-1)$, $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{105}}{2}$

$3\mathbb{Z}_K=p_3^2$ where $p_3=(3)$

$5\mathbb{Z}_K=p_5^2$ where $p_5=(5)$

But $(\frac{1+\sqrt{105}}{2}+4)=p_2''p_3$ where $N(p_2'')=2$ so the classes $[p_2'']=[p_3]^{-1}=[p_3]$.

I'm not sure how I can use the element of norm $-5$.

$(10+\sqrt{105})=p_5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $p_2=p_2'$ already, correct?  Second, the correct notation is generally $\mathcal{O}_K$, not $\mathbb{Z}_K$.  That's a mathcal O.

Third, I don't think it's true that $3\mathcal{O}_K=p_3^2$ where $p_3=(3)$.  In fact, $(3)=3\mathcal{O}_K=p_3^2$ where $p_3=(3, \sqrt{105})$.  The same thing for $(5)$: it's $p_5^2$ where $p_5=(5, \sqrt{105})$.

Now you determined an element of norm $-5$.  Its principal ideal must then be $p_5$, since this is all that $(5)$ factors into, correct?  So in fact $p_5=(10+\sqrt{105})$.

Your claim that $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{105}}{2}+4\right)=p''_2p_3$ can be checked now, because there is actually only one prime $p_2$ and one prime $p_3$.  You can do this yourself if you like!

The only remaining question is why $p_2$ and $p_3$ are not principal.  Do you know this already?  Do you have an argument for it?

Comment: Why is $p_2=p_2'$?. Yes, your decomposition is right (I forgot about $\sqrt{105})$. Why is $p_5$ not principal? Is it because $p_5=(5,\sqrt{105})$ and $p_5=(10+\sqrt{105})$?

Comment: @Walter It is principal, you found a generator: $10+\sqrt{105}$.  Right?  And in the case of $p_2$ and $p_2'$, is it true that $\alpha-1\in(2, \alpha+1)$?  Can you write $\alpha-1$ as a linear combination of $2$ and $\alpha+1$?  That's what this notation really means.

Comment: @Walter yes that seems good enough.  Again, as long as you know already that $p_2$ is not principal.

Comment: Ok, why did we not worry about $p_5$ then? Is it because it is principal?

Comment: That is correct.  You're just trying to figure out the structure of the group; you can (and should) get rid of unnecessary ideals like $p_5$.  That's trivial in the class group, so there's no reason to worry about it.

Comment: Could I use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168800/prove-that-if-neither-a-nor-a-are-squares-modulo-d-then-no-integral-idea to show $p_2$ is not principal?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's about right.  I'm always careful about the prime $2$, though, it takes separate work.  More succinctly, though: if you had an element $u=a+b\sqrt{105}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers or half integers, with $N(u)=\pm 2$, then $a^2-105b^2=\pm2$ or $(2a)^2-105(2b)^2=\pm 8$, an equation in integers.  Take it $\mod 5$ and see what's wrong.

Comment: Anyways for your equation mod $5$: $a^2=+/- 3$ contradicting $a$ being an integer.

Comment: It's easier to use the $\sqrt{105}$ norm instead of the $\alpha$ norm because there's no cross term to deal with, and it's equivalent besides.

Comment: Hello again, I made a mistake before. $p_2=(\alpha), p_2' = (\alpha+1)$ My question is do I show $p_3$ or $p_2$ in not principal? Which one?

Comment: @Walter What do you mean $p_2=(\alpha)$? The number $2$ needs to be in the ideal, yes? But it is not in $(\alpha)$.

Comment: @Walter I'm sorry, I understand the issue now. I think the method above shows that both $p_2$ and $p_2'$ are not principal. They are in fact just conjugates of each other.

Comment: Yes I mean 2, alpha and 2,alpha+1